# In a makefile, how VPATH works?

Tags: linux, makefile

in the following website
[https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/](http://make.paulandlesley.org/vpath.html)

the author says:

> VPATH was designed to find sources, not targets.

but in GNU make's manual, it says:

> The value of the make variable VPATH specifies a list of directories
> that make should search. Most often, the directories are expected to
> contain prerequisite files that are not in the current directory;
> however, **make uses VPATH as a search list for both prerequisites and
> targets of rules**.

what does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNU Make manual says that you *can* use VPATH to find targets. Paul Smith is saying that you generally *shouldn't*. (Whether VPATH was or wasn't originally 
designed for that purpose is moot.)

There are a few reasons why using VPATH this way can cause problems (none of them damning) but the page at [paulandlesley](http://make.paulandlesley.org/vpath.html) is specifically talking about using VPATH naively to build targets in remote locations (which just doesn't work), in the context of multi-architecture builds.

Comment: could you give an explanation why such builds with remote locations wouldn't work for multi-arch?

Comment: @woodz: That page explains pretty clearly why using VPATH that way doesn't work in general; the problem is more obvious with multi-arch builds, which involve more object files, usually organized in arch-specific directories. Very briefly: VPATH can't find what isn't yet there.

Answer (score 7):

It means exactly what it says. `make` will look both for things needed to build something and things already built to see if it needs to be rebuilt.

A typical scenario is if you use a temporary build directory where you place object files before linking or creating an archive. Then you want `make` to look there too to see what needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: @CyberRusher I'm not sure I understand your comment. Either `make` uses it to search for targets, or it does not. As far as I know, it does. What do you mean with "not good" in this context? I've used `VPATH` for just this in my own makefiles and it works very well.